# How to convert multi select form field with GET tto have propper URL?

Tags: url, forms, get, multi-select

```
<select name="channel[]" multiple="multiple">
    <option value="pants">Pants</option>
    <option value="tshirts">T-Shirts</option>
    <option value="sweats">Sweats</option>
</select>
```

So, form is GET, and if I select multiple, and when I click on submit URL is like:

```
?channel[]=pants&channel[]=tshirts
```

I need it to be like:

```
?channel=pants+tshirts
```

Answer (score 0):

This cannot be achieved with an HTML only form. You'll have to incorporate javascript to manipulate the value of *channel*.